# If/else Performance

Tags: performance, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out the difference in CPU usage and performance comparing two if/else statements, take the following functions

```
function f(x):
  if(condition) return true;
  else return false;

function f'(x):
  if(condition) return true;
  return false;
```

The purpose of the function is not important, of course in both cases you want to return true if the 'if' is true, otherwise return false.

Both pieces of code do the same thing, I'm thinking with regards to performance and CPU usage, would there be any difference between these two programs when removing the else statement and using the sequential execution to do the 'else' instead, or when compiled would the difference just be lost?

Comment: It wasn't in any particular language was just using quasi pseudocode as i thought it made more sense

Comment: Have you tried compiling comparable code in the language of your choice and seeing if there is a difference in the resulting low-level instructions?  Also, I'm not sure if this question can be asked in a general, language-agnostic sense because the answer may very well depend on the language and programming environment in use.

Comment: These functions have the same CFG (upside down V, or diamond if you append a dedicated exit-block) and the nodes contain identical code, so there really shouldn't be a difference.. but it depends on the compiler

Comment: No need to think and guess. It is trivial to measure this and _know_.

Comment: @BACON just ran a quick c file attempt in gcc and they are exactly the same

Comment: I have to admit the code about is strange.

Why don't you write

bool function(x) return (condition)?

Comment: @user1462442: depending on the language, `condition` is not necessarily boolean.

Comment: @user1462442 I have come across more advanced examples in a similar style, just wanted to break the problem down to its most basic form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between the two functions. Any half-decent compiler would generate identical code for them.

Because the `if` branch contains `return` at the end, `else` in the first program is redundant. When the program is translated to machine instructions, you end up with something like this:

```
start:   LD $condition  -- Check condition
         JZ else_br     -- Conditional jump
         LD true_val
         RET            -- Return true
else_br: LD false_val
         RET            -- Return false
```

In the second program `else` branch is empty, so the sequence of instructions would be the same.